# How to append multiple lines to a file without last newline?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, io-redirection

I have a very long string that is split in chunks. I want to append them to a file without putting the newline character using bash.

Example:
First append

```
cat >> abc.sh << EOL
echo "bla bla"
ifcon
EOL
```

Second append

```
cat >> abc.sh << EOL
fig -a
uname -a
EOL
```

And the file *abc.sh* should be:

```
echo "bla bla"
ifconfig -a
uname -a
```

and not

```
echo "bla bla"
ifcon
fig -a
uname -a
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<<` always includes a trailing newline (except for an empty here document).

You'd need to do either:

```
printf %s 'echo "bla bla"
ifcon' >> file
```

Or use a command that removes the trailing newline character instead of `cat`:

```
awk '{printf "%s", l $0; l=RT}' << EOF >> file
echo "blah bla"
ifcon
EOF
```

(Or `perl -pe'chomp if eof'`)

Or, where here-documents are implemented with temporary files (`bash`, `zsh`, `pdksh`, AT&T `ksh`, Bourne, not `mksh`, `dash` nor `yash`), on GNU/Linux systems, you could do:

```
{ 
  chmod u+w /dev/stdin && # only needed in bash 5+
    truncate -s-1 /dev/stdin &&
    cat
} << EOF >> file
echo "blah bla"
ifcon
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo` with the -n switch:

```
 echo -n "blah blah" >> file
```